# Android: How can i refresh a view every time when a tab bar item is clicked?

Tags: android

I am making an application with TabBar.In the Tab Bar there are 3 tabs. One of those tabs is a linked list which is linked with a another view which adds data. I want to refresh that view every time when i click that tab so that i can get updated my view. How can i do that? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Add your code in onResume() method, that should refresh.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to refresh the List View when ever you want without going to here and there from the same page then you may wish to implement Pull to Refresh Functionality in Android App.

Use this link and download the app and check for the same....it helps you very much because I have implemented the same.

https://github.com/johannilsson/android-pulltorefresh

Answer (score 2):

Put your code in OnResume() method then it will refresh.

```
@Override
    protected void onResume() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onResume();
    }
```

Comment: My code is in oncreate. Do i need it again put it in onresume()?

Comment: This did not worked for me. I am calling my webservice code in onresume. But i am not able to load the view with new data.

Answer (score 0):

```
 @Override
    protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();

    if (debug) Log.d(TAG,"onResume()");
    if (dbHelper == null) {
        dbHelper = new DBHelper(this);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

First, put the two tab view in same TabActivity.
Then, put the  XXXX.notifyDataSetChanged() of the view you want refresh in onResume().

Don't forget update the data source of that view correspond before.

```
@Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        // update data source first
        // your notifyDataSetChanged() call
        XXXX.notifyDataSetChanged();
    }
```